# Issues trying to download Windows 8.1 using official downloader

Tags: windows-8

I had been trying to download Windows 8.1 ISO from the last 3-4 days but a silly issue is preventing me to download it.As many posts over the internet explain,I tried to use generic keys to download(as I don't have Windows 8),but the installer always shows "**We can't connect right now,please check you internet connection.**".Isn't it silly?,I have a working internet connection.No matter whatever key I use it always ends at this message.I've tried every single generic key,and almost every key was accepted by the installer as valid,but then the message.

Can anyone please explain why is this happening and any workarounds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike previous Windows service packs, Windows 8.1 is obtained as a download through Windows Store for users of retail or OEM copies of Windows 8 and RT.

and

> ...versions of Windows 8.1 distributed as ISO images do not accept Windows 8 product keys

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Windows_8.1)

So to reiterate, you need to have a licensed, legal copy of Windows 8 to be able to download and use Windows 8.1 (you need to have Windows 8 installed to do this).

In lieu of that, you would either need to obtain and use a legal license for Windows 8, install it and then download and upgrade to Windows 8.1 through the Windows Store for free or obtain and use a legal license for Windows 8.1 and download the ISO for that elsewhere.

I am unsure what you mean by 'generic key' but as far as I know, only full and legal license keys will work for installing/upgrading to Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thanks,that's the information I was lacking.+1 for explaining workaround.

Comment: Not a problem :)